# How to set request headers for AutoHotkey UrlDownloadToFile request to SEC?

Tags: download, autohotkey, request-headers

I am attempting to use AutoHotkey [`UrlDownloadToFile`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/URLDownloadToFile.htm) to access data on SEC.gov:

```
UrlDownloadToFile, %sURL%, %sSaveAs%
```

where `sURL` looks like:

```
https://www.SEC.gov/Archives/edgar/data/<document ID>/xslFormDX01/primary_doc.xml
```

Instead of the desired webpage content, I'm getting a response with the title "Your Request Originates from an Undeclared Automated Tool", which says "Please declare your traffic by updating your user agent to include company specific information." and directs me to [sec.gov/developer](https://www.sec.gov/developer) for instructions. That page says, "The [SEC]'s HTTPS file system allows comprehensive access to the SEC's EDGAR ... filings by corporations, funds, and individuals.  For full documentation, please see [Accessing EDGAR Data](https://www.sec.gov/os/accessing-edgar-data)." That page says:

```
Please declare your user agent in request headers:
Sample Declared Bot Request Headers:
- User-Agent: Sample Company Name AdminContact@<sample company domain>.com
- Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
- Host: www.sec.gov
We do not offer technical support for developing or debugging scripted processes.
```

So it appears that the SEC does not object to my doing this automated download, as long as I set those headers (and keep my requests to under ten per second). But how to I do that? How can I set those headers for my call to `UrlDownloadToFile`?

I found an open source tool for downloading SEC data, `edgarWebR`, whose [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/edgarWebR/readme/README.html) says, "Users of this library are advised to set a custom user-agent by setting the environment variable `EDGARWEBR_USER_AGENT`." Would doing that solve my problem? If so, where and how do I set that environment variable?

I found [GitHub code for a function](https://github.com/Masonjar13/AHK-Library/blob/master/Lib/urlDownloadToFile.ahk) that appears to be a replacement for AHK's `UrlDownloadToFile` and provides the ability to set the user agent. However, I don't understand how to implement that function and it doesn't come with any documentation that explains that. It doesn't say what language it's written in, but it looks like it might be C. I don't have a C compiler on this computer, but if I did, I don't know where I would call this function.

I found a [Microsoft forum Q&A](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f0713c39-89b5-4516-93fc-75f6aee696ee/set-referrer-or-user-agent-string-for-urldownloadtofile-with-ibindstatuscallback) that seems relevant, suggesting using [`UrlMkSetSessionOption`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775125(VS.85).aspx) or [`WebBrowser::Navigate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161356(v=vs.110).aspx). For documentation, the link it gives is dead, but is [preserved at Archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20200121030022/http://www.lukepaynesoftware.com/articles/programming-tutorials/changing-the-user-agent-in-a-web-browser-control/). Unfortunately, although the Q&A are specific to using `URLDownloadToFile`, I don't understand how to implement either suggested technique for my AHK script.

All of the above three things appear to cover setting the user agent, but the SEC instructions quoted above say to also set `Accept-Encoding` and `Host`, so do I also need to do that separately? If so, how?

Obviously, I'm over my head here in the technicalities of what I'm trying to do. I hope someone can explain what I need to do in order to run my AHK script (or perhaps an alternative technique for automating the download of those files) in a way that satisfies the SEC's requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't get any answers, I used a workaround to get AutoHotkey to open each URL in the browser (`run, %sURL%`) and then save the resulting webpage (`send` Alt-F-A, `send` filename) and close it (`send` Alt-F4). This worked mostly, although I had to fix a number of problems manually.

That solved my problem of how to get the files, but it didn't answer my question of how to set request headers in order to do it the right way. So I won't accept this answer in case someone comes along later and properly answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like below is what you need. I have NO familiarity with SEC.gov, so you will

---

have to provide input and edits based on your experience with that website (like document ID). I added a method for getting a cookie that might work based on the cookie that I saw returned by sec.gov in the response headers in debugger console in Chrome. This is the cookie I got back that expires in about 8 hours (ak_bmsc=5EF62DAF005C6A95904F7ED7CCED9D78~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQFC0tF+cmqpSBAQAAGJavoxCRBM3XBiKPn8e24CgXNLo+q6fI5C4VOJAkqdQdlHpsf2p08VHMcp10NI9rhpcoiI1i8CFQEvrR9b1SyCA9wN6sCAhoioLMvuqsYCwvVr21+AXb+XTvs65Kc70n5P7bEDYsvvWAFC5L+jdAQ+mLlcDTWF7twH2Lg1vYQAbxcje8OnbTDSldM2IGsWltH4ii1h73ZYPqlcTMWf/uh9AbKAlk+x50YQ1bUkTGdl+HZgulE6crPxHOqy4Q2PbXi2QwgylnYG9VTkmMzCnLi+clfWFQVuTz1i85x+YO9B4/eV3VHTYgFFk/SEmerp0kZbmzhT/RdFneLSaOOjg0KfHFR0tsKrlY1Ys=;), which is why you would want to get a new cookie each time you do a batch of these requests. I tested it on an online regex tester, so it should work.

```
; GET COOKIE IDEA (EDIT)
Global reqCookie
secReq := getReq("www.sec.gov")
If (foundCookie := regexMatch(secReq.getAllResponseHeaders(), "U)Set\-?Cookie:[\s\r\n]+\K(\S+\;)", cookie)) {
    reqCookie := cookie1
} Else {
    Msgbox, Didn't find a cookie!
    Return
}

itWorked := urlDownloadToFileSEC(A_Desktop . "\SEC Download.xml", "1548527/000154852712000001")

Msgbox % (itWorked ? "It Worked!" : "Something went wrong")
Return

urlDownloadToFileSEC(FilePath, docID, timeoutMS=60000, bAsync=false)
    r := comObjCreate("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    r.Open("GET", "https://www.SEC.gov/Archives/edgar/data/" . docID . "/xslFormDX01/primary_doc.xml", bAsync)
    r.SetTimeouts(timeoutMS, timeoutMS, timeoutMS, timeoutMS)
    r.SetRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Sample Company Name AdminContact@<sample company domain>.com")
     ; DO NOT KNOW WHAT YOU WOULD ACTUALLY WANT TO PUT IN THE ABOVE USER AGENT.
    r.SetRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
    r.SetRequestHeader("Host", "www.sec.gov")
    r.SetRequestHeader("cookie", reqCookie)
    r.Send()
    if (bAsync) {
        Return r
    ; you have to use WaitForResponse method to check for it later.
    }
    if (r.Status="200") {
        fileText := r.ResponseText
        fileAppend, %fileText%, %filePath%
    } ; ERRORLEVEL CONTAINS WRITE SUCCESS.
    Return (r.Status="200" ? true : false)
 
 ; NEW FUNCTION!
getReq(URL, bAsync=false, timeouts=60000, reqHeadersMap="") {
    Req := comObjCreate("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    Req.Open("GET", URL, bAsync)
    Req.SetTimeouts(timeouts, timeouts, timeouts, timeouts)
    if (isObject(reqHeadersMap)) {
        For key, value in reqHeadersMap {
            Req.SetRequestHeader(Key, Value)
        }
    }
    Req.Send()
    if (bAsync) {
        Return Req
    }
    ErrorLevel := (Req.Status==200 ? true : false)
    Return Req
}
```

Comment: Interesting. The code runs okay without an error from the SEC, but it doesn't get any file contents. I looped through several iterations and each time, the SciTE4AutoHotkey debugger says the value of `fileText` has the value of two unknown characters and NotePad++ says the saved files all contain "`US`?`BS`". So this function appears to be allowing me to access the SEC URL without an error, but it is not retrieving any data.

Comment: Does the doc ID require the chevrons or is that just to indicate a placeholder for the doc ID? This is what I meant with regard to edits and lack of familiarity with that site, there may need to be some minor changes. Try downloading a doc with the Chrome debugger open. It will give you more data about the actual http request. Also it might require a XML HTTP Request object, since that seems to be the file type in the url. The example demonstrates setting headers which was my main point.

Comment: The angle brackets or chevrons indicate where a doc ID goes. Here's an example doc URL: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1548527/000154852712000001/xslFormDX01/primary_doc.xml . I don't have Chrome installed, but use Firefox. Do you want to try your code on that URL and see if you are able to retrieve it?

Comment: OK I edited the code based on that link. It appears that the doc ID has two parts from that link. The angle brackets are not part of the doc id and are just used to indicate a placeholder (side note I take time to answer these questions at home on my Mac, so cannot test it from here). Also I took a look at the request headers and you may need to make an initial request to sec.gov to get a cookie (which will be in GetAllResponseHeaders on initial request in plain text, and most likely will need to be parsed out.)

Comment: I don't understand the second half of that comment. Since I've made several requests, should I have the cookie you're talking about? I have nine cookies from SEC.gov. If I find the cookie you're talking about, what am I supposed to parse from it, and what am I supposed to do with that information? And why are you talking about this cookie, which the SEC doesn't mention in its documentation?

Comment: I added an edit to the code, but I am not sure how exactly the cookie will be formatted.